# Can someone explain what the 'Agence technique de l'information sur l'hospitalisation' is ?

Tags: sens

can someone please provide an explan- or translation for

> ATIH - Agence technique de l'information sur l'hospitalisation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translation for the [ATIH](http://www.atih.sante.fr/) given by the [Institute for research and information on health economics](http://www.irdes.fr/english/home.html) (IRDES) is :

> Agency for Information on Hospital Care (AIHC).

They have a glossary you can download [here](http://www.irdes.fr/documentation/methodes-et-glossaires.html). The one you need is *[French Institutions on Public Health](http://www.irdes.fr/documentation/documents/institutions-francaises-dans-le-domaine-de-la-sante-traduction-anglaise.pdf)*.